# How to solve Shopify Themekit Error After Installation? giving theme is not recognized in terminal

Tags: themes, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I was trying to install themekit from shopify github docs. I have also installed the themekit successfully, but now whenever i check its proper installation using command "theme" it throws me an error showing theme is not recognized although the themekit is showing installed, I have tried doing Refresh of powershell and manual installation but nothing works, Can i find an solution?[Please check this screenshot from my powershell showing theme not recognized]